# highchart - How to change yaxis position on polar chart?

Tags: charts, highcharts

Please see the following chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/A9v4R/

I want that the yaxis labels will be where the -90 point, it's relocated because i changed the startangle.

The xaxis now is great for me but i need to change the position of the yaxis.
Please tell me how can i do that.

i tried to do:

```
    yAxis: {
        tickPositions: [-40, -35, -30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, 0],
        labels: {
            x: -13,

        }
```

Thanks,
Tal.

Comment: So how it should look like? which lables where should be?